# Make movie clip 'Enemy' follow 'player' instead of walking on set xy axis? Flash, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, instance, movieclip

curious to know if I can somehow make the enemy movie clip in my flash game follow the movie clip the player controls, called 'player' in this instance. At the minute, it's just set to walk -3 on X and 1.5 on Y.

Not really sure if I need to post any code on here, just in case, here is my code inside the Enemy Movie clip.
Thanks in advance!

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var catxSpeed:Number = -3;
var catySpeed:Number = 1.5;
var myParent:*;
var ground:Number;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var health:Number;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatecat);

function updatecat(event:Event):void
{
this.x += catxSpeed;
if(myParent.player.hitTestObject(this))
{
    myParent.hit();
}
this.y += catySpeed;
if(jumping == true)
{
    catySpeed +=1;
    if(this.y >= ground)
    {
        catxSpeed = -3;
        catySpeed = 0;
        this.y = ground;
        jumping = false;
        if(health < 1)
        {
            shutDown();
        }
    }
}
}

function activate(passParent:*):void
{
ground = this.y;
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatecat);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hit);
myParent = passParent;
health = Math.round(myParent.randomise(2,4));
}

function shutDown():void
{
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatecat);
this.parent.removeChild(this);
}

function hit(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
catxSpeed = 30;
catySpeed = -15;
jumping = true;
myParent.addToScore(1);
health--;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (enemy.x > this.x) this.x += catxSpeed;
else this.x -= catxSpeed;


if (enemy.y > this.y) this.y += catySpeed;
else this.y -= catySpeed;
```

Comment: Do I place that inside the 'player'?
Sorry, not really sure how to implement that/ how it will follow the 'player' instance around? Sorry, i'm relatively new to this! Do you mind walking me through it?

Comment: I'd suggest to have one controller/main/mediator class, which instanciates the enemy and the cat. it's probably best to have only one listener to stage.ENTER_FRAME in the controller. the controller tells the cat/enemy how to move, and checks for a hit. keep the cat and enemy classes stupid and move all the logic to the controller.